# Laravel + Vue restrict access to some api routes

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I have laravel 8 backend app, serving as API for frontend using Vue 3

In my routes/api.php I have
`Route::post('/teachers', [TeacherController::class, 'index'])->name('teachers');`
This will return list of teachers to be used in VueJS.

How do I restrict so that only my VueJS app can access api/teachers ? I successfully hitting the api above using POSTMAN, which I expect it to be failed.
I have laravel sanctum installed, although i'm not so sure whether this is something sanctum can help with.

Thanks

Comment: If you want the URL to only be used when authenticated, then you have to rewrite your route as: `->middleware('auth:sanctum')`, but if you only want this route to work for VueJS and nothing else, then I think that is not possible or it is too complex...

Comment: @matiaslauriti it's not only for authenticated user. Yes i only want this route to be accessed by my own frontend vue